# Elixir: compile warning "the result of the expression is ignored "

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm implementing a `crash` function in a `GenServer` to test the behavior of the supervisor and registry that will manage this process. Work is done in Elixir but I believe it may also concern Erlang.

I could have called `raise()` but in the first place I implemented `1/0` as the reason for crash. The compiler being a smart guy, for the following code:

```
def handle_cast(:crash, state) do
  a = 1 / 0
  {:noreply, state}    
end
```

I got the warning:

```
warning: this expression will fail with ArithmeticError
  lib/xyz/worker.ex:47
```

Fair. After all, even old C or C++ compilers were able to detect this kind of things. I tried a library call replacing `a = 1 / 0` by `a = 1 / :math.sin(0)`. Same warning. My curiosity woke up and I tried different things with the same outcome. Actually, it looks like this is not so easy to fool the compiler! Eventually, I put:

```
a = 1 / Enum.reduce([0, 1, -1], 0, fn(n, acc) -> n+acc end)
```

and got a different  warning:

```
warning: the result of the expression is ignored (suppress the warning by assigning the expression to the _ variable)
  lib/xyz/worker.ex:50
```

line 50 being `a = 1 / Enum.reduce(...)`.

I spent a couple of hours trying different things with always getting either warning.

I believe the first one is raised because the compiler is able to precalculate the result out of constant arguments and of function type and inline eventually the operation `1 / 0`.

Yet I don't understand the second warning. In one of the tests, I wrote :

```
def handle_cast(:crash, state) do
  a = 1 / Enum.reduce([0, 1, -1], 0, fn(n, acc) -> n+acc end)
  # {:noreply, state}    
end
```

which actually suppresses the warning, but I really don't understand why.

**NB.1**: Versions:

```
maurice@mickey> elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.6.1 (compiled with OTP 19)
```

**NB.2**: I'm aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752656/erlang-record-expression-ignored-warning#5753201), yet I don't think the reply applies here.

For the time being, I'll be calling `raise(...)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short version

The warning is actually telling you what to do: replace `a = ...` with `_ = ...`.

### Long version

In your examples at hand you assign the result of the operation to a variable called `a`. The compile notices that you never use that variable again, so it complains about it.

Elixir knows a "special" variable for that case called `_`. When doing `_ = ...` or `def my_function(_, second_paramter)` you basically tell the compiler:

> I don't want to use that value, so please don't complain

To provide more information about the ignored value, you can also prefix a variable with an underscore (`_`), which serves the same purpose. In your case that could be `_a = ...`.

This is mainly useful when ignoring arguments in a function, without leaving the reader to guess what that argument was about. So `def get(:thing, _)` could become `def get(:thing, _opts)`.

---

Then you asked why the commented out version didn't produce that error. The answer to that lies in the fact that the return value of a function is equal to the last statement of that function.

So this function

```
def my_function do
  1
  2
  3
end
```

returns 3, while this function

```
def my_function do
  :a
  :b
end
```

returns `:b`. As such in your example

```
def handle_cast(:crash, state) do
  a = 1 / Enum.reduce([0, 1, -1], 0, fn(n, acc) -> n+acc end)
  # {:noreply, state}    
end
```

You commented out the `# {:noreply, state}` tuple and the `a = ...` statement becomes the last one in the function. Since now you create the variable `a` and evaluate it as part of the "return", the compiler stops complaining.

On the other hand, a fair case could be made that a variable assignment in the last line of a function is useless. So this might actually warrant a low priority issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir).

Comment: All this makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fool the compiler till the end, reassign `state` variable:

```rb
def handle_cast(:crash, state) do
  state = Enum.reduce([0, 1, -1], 0, fn(n, acc) ->
    n + acc
  end)
  {:noreply, state}    
end
```

That way the compiler will think `state` assignment is necessary (since it’s used as a return value.)

Comment: This generates both warnings: `the result of the expression is ignored (suppress the warning by assigning the expression to the _ variable)` and `this expression will fail with ArithmeticError`